# Play sound when certain text appears in browser

Tags: browser-addons, accessibility

I'm looking for a browser, or browser extension that will play an audio file when certain text is displayed (or even buried in the html).

Specifically I'd like a sound to play when GMail tells me "The conversation has been archived" but I can also see this being useful for all manner of assistive technology reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that occurs to me is something along the lines of an [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com) script.

Comment: so, autoit has access to the DOM inside of the browser? :)

Comment: With a couple caveats, "Yes."  Have a google, you might be surprised.